# Ag-Grid : How to get the focused cell value

Tags: grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to get the focused cell value at the time focussing on the cell by using the keyboard arrow keys

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can either get the focused cell by using

```
var focusedCell = gridOptions.api.getFocusedCell();
```

or use the **onCellFocused** event.

Both give you the following properties:

- rowIndex: number
- column: Column

Use the row-index to retrieve the row-node:

```
var row = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);
```

After that you can use those properties to retrieve the raw value of the cell:

```
var cellValue = gridOptions.api.getValue(colKey, row.node)
```

Comment: @Mallikarjuna - I know it's been almost a month since you solved this, but do you have an example of how you implemented this with keyboard navigation? Thanks!

Comment: Selected row is not always focused row, so this did the trick for me. Keep it up!

Comment: how do you get `colKey`?

Comment: @PhilippMunin `params.column.colId`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the API changes between UI library bindings, but this worked for me with vue:

```js
 const cellFocused = (evt) => {
  const focusedCell =  evt.api.getFocusedCell();
  const row = evt.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(focusedCell.rowIndex)
  const cellValue = evt.api.getValue(focusedCell.column, row)
  console.log("xxx cell was value", cellValue);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer might have worked in past but not now.
Row.node does not exist, and colSelected is the string representation of the column Header not the Id.
The simplest way to get a selected cell's value (Either upon clicking or right clicking) is:

```
let colSelected = params.column.colId;
let selectedCell = gridOptions.api.getFocusedCell();
let row = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(selectedCell.rowIndex);

const value = gridOptions.api.getValue(colSelected,row);
```