# How To Get Selected Row Column Index Of AgGrid (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Currently I am able to get the row data using [gridApi](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/) but unable to get the info about what is the column index of selected row?

The function **[this.gridApi.getSelectedRows()](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/)** has no properties for this.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398168/1063878

Comment: row index of selected row?

Comment: no I want the column index of selected row

Comment: @ Alexander Zbinden this gives only current selected cell not the column index of selected cell

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305211/how-to-retrieve-the-column-index-in-ag-grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the displayed column index then try this, using the **columnApi**:

```
var focusedCell = this.gridApi.getFocusedCell();    
this.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().indexOf(focusedCell.column)
```